# Basic jQuery Slider (BJQS) not applying styles to jQuery and XML generated li elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml

I'm trying to use Basic jQuery Slider with a list generated by another piece of jQuery and some XML, but I'm finding that BJQS doesn't want to apply styles to the li elements that are being generated, so they're not being hidden and faded in.

Into the document head I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bjqs.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

All of which are needed for bjqs anyway and are loading fine according to Firebug.

In the body I have:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "images-revision.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    var path = jQuery(xml).find('path').text();

    jQuery(xml).find("image").each(function() {
        jQuery(".bjqs").append("<li><img src='" + path + jQuery(this).find("filename").text() + "'/></li>");
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Which reads from a list of images in an XML file before listing them inside the  in place for the BJQS.

Then I have the slide container:

```
<div id="banner-fade">
    <ul class='bjqs'>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Followed by the parameters I want to use to control the slide:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
        jQuery('#banner-fade').bjqs({
            height      : 198,
            width       : 956,
            automatic : true, // automatic
            showcontrols : false, // show next and prev controls
            usecaptions : false, // show captions for images using the image title tag
            responsive : false, // enable responsive capabilities
            showmarkers : false, // Show individual slide markers
            // animation values
            animtype : 'fade', // accepts 'fade' or 'slide'
            animduration : 750, // how fast the animation are
            animspeed : 5000, // the delay between each slide
        });
    });
</script>
```

The correct styles are being applied to #banner-fade and ul.bjqs, but not the generated li elements, which are the parts that are hidden and shown to rotate between images.

I've a feeling it's got something to do with the BJQS stuff being called before the lis are created, but I'm not going to pretend to know what to do about that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, using on window load http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ instead of document ready for the section with the bjqs parameters fixed this.

So I replaced this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
  jQuery('#banner-fade').bjqs({
```

With this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
```